# Question about improper integral

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, integration

Does $\forall \epsilon \in (0,a]: \int _{\epsilon}^{a} f(x)dx =0$ imply that $\lim_{h \rightarrow 0} \int _h^a f(x)dx=0$. I guess it is somehow the definition of it, but I need to know this exactly.

Comment: Yes. What is the limit of a constant function $g$ equal to $c$ on the boundary of its interval of definition $(0,a]$? For every $\epsilon>0$, there exists $\delta>0$ (just take $\delta=a$) such that for all $x\in (0,a]$, $|x-0|\leq \delta$ implies $|g(x)-c|=|c-c|=0\leq \epsilon$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's even stronger. The limit only says that the integral *goes* to zero when $h$ goes to zero, whereas the first statement says that it *is* zero for *all* $h$.

In fact, your first statement implies that $f = 0$ a.e. on $(0,a]$, I think.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

If we have a function $f$ s.t.
$$f(x)=0\quad \forall x\in(0,a]$$
then what's $\lim_{x\to0}f(x)$?